# Keep focused on pop up window until closed

Tags: javascript, html, popup

I want to keep the focus in the new popup window and refrain user on clicking the parent window unless the popup window is closed. My code below focus on pop up window every time the link was clicked. I want to keep the focused on the popup window every time it is open.

Below is my html code.

```js
function PopupCenter(url, title, w, h) {
  var dualScreenLeft = window.screenLeft != undefined ? window.screenLeft : screen.left;
  var dualScreenTop = window.screenTop != undefined ? window.screenTop : screen.top;
  var width = window.innerWidth ? window.innerWidth : document.documentElement.clientWidth ? document.documentElement.clientWidth : screen.width;
  var height = window.innerHeight ? window.innerHeight : document.documentElement.clientHeight ? document.documentElement.clientHeight : screen.height;

  var left = ((width / 2) - (w / 2)) + dualScreenLeft;
  var top = ((height / 2) - (h / 2)) + dualScreenTop;
  var newWindow = window.open(url, title, 'scrollbars=yes, width=' + w + ', height=' + h + ', top=' + top + ', left=' + left);

  // Puts focus on the newWindow
  if (window.focus) {
    newWindow.focus();
  }
}
```

```html
<a href="" class="btn btn-outline btn-info btn-xs" onClick="PopupCenter('transfer.php?id=<?php echo $putIn;?>','xtf','980','350');">Transfer</a>
```

Answer (score 1):

You can achieve `focus` by:

```
function popitup(url) {
  newwindow = window.open(url, 'name', 'height=200,width=150');
  if (window.focus) {
    newwindow.focus()
  }

  if (!newwindow.closed) {
    newwindow.focus()
  }
  return false;
}
```

**EDIT :**
If the above doesn't work then the other way is to remove focus from parent window

```
<html>
<head>
<script type="text/javascript">

var popupWindow=null;

function child_open()
{ 

popupWindow =window.open('new.jsp',"_blank","directories=no, status=no, menubar=no, scrollbars=yes, resizable=no,width=600, height=280,top=200,left=200");

}
function parent_disable() {
if(popupWindow && !popupWindow.closed)
popupWindow.focus();
}
</script>
</head>
<body onFocus="parent_disable();" onclick="parent_disable();">
    <a href="javascript:child_open()">Click me</a>
</body>    
</html>
```

Comment: Hi. it didn't work. it didn't keep the focus when I clicked the parent window.

Comment: Hi @shubham agrawal. It just open new popup every time the link was clicked.